# How to fill out a form field without a name in webbrowser control?

Tags: html, vb.net, automation, webbrowser-control

In the past, I used the code below to fill out a form field using the webbrowser control in VB.Net. The page I am working with doesn't have name field for the inputbox, so my code doesn't work. How would I fill out the input box defined at the bottom of this post in bold?

```
Dim iPage As HtmlDocument
iPage = wb1.Document
iPage.All.Item("case_num").InnerText() = caseNum
iPage.All.Item("button1").InvokeMember("click")
```

---

```
**<input type="text" id="tbSymbolLookupMain" mode="mixed" autocomplete="off" defaulttxt="Enter Name or Symbol(s)" value="Enter Name or Symbol(s)" class="SymbolLookup  fhHandleFocus fhDefault">**
```

Answer (score 0):

Is input in your question actual data you work with? You can try to use [HtmlDocument.GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) to find it by id. But unless I'm mistaken what you do should already work as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4b70was%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) states Item("some name") on HtmlElementCollection uses "some name" to match both by Id and Name. So you might use your usual way but provide **id** instead of name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?

Comment: is "<input type="text" **id="tbSymbolLookupMain"** mode="mixed" autocomplete="off" defaulttxt="Enter Name or Symbol(s)" value="Enter Name or Symbol(s)" class="SymbolLookup  fhHandleFocus fhDefault">" the date you have your issue with? Then try your usual way as 

iPage.All.Item(**"tbSymbolLookupMain"**)

Comment: That's the one, but it doesn't seem to work. This pops an error?? iDoc.All.Item("tbSymbolLookupMain").InnerText() = symbol

Comment: Could you please provide error details? Also does iDoc.All.Item("tbSymbolLookupMain") return anything at all? Can you find any other HTML-element? It is stupid guess but didn't you make a typo in ID?

Comment: Wait, which part do you think I made a typo?

Comment: The place where there might by typo is ID name i.e. **tbSymbolLookupMain**. However this was just guess. The really interesting questions in my opinion are: "Does iDoc.All.Item("tbSymbolLookupMain") return anything at all (or Nothing)?" and "Can you find any other HTML-element?". It might be that the issue with iDoc for example.